# Correct way to design classes

Tags: c++, design-patterns

How should you design classes?
Say for example you want to use a class to design a computer.
My approach would be to store objects in the class:
RAM, HARD DISK, CPU, MOTHERBOARD

Provide functions to build the computer:

OBTAIN MOTHERBAORD func

ADD HARD DISK to MOTHERBOARD func

ADD CPU to MOTHERBOARD func

ADD RAM to MOTHERBOARD func

Provide other functions the computer can do:
PlAY MARIO KART func

Is there any problem with this approach?
Is there any good class design practices one should follow?

Comment: there are probably millions of design practices, whether they are good is a matter of debate. Usually, what works is good ;)

Comment: You shouldn't be thinking in terms of concrete things such as "memory" or "CPU" and instead in more abstract terms like "component" or "connector". For example, a CPU is just a component that fits into a particular socket, and a motherboard is a component that has that socket. As a socket is just a type of connector it all works out. When it comes to "functions" that's entirely subjective. Can a computer without a CPU play a game? No. What about without a hard drive? Yes!

Comment: Why what is the difference?
An object can either be abstract or concrete
Component is akin is saying object. You can still have concrete component and abstract component...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topic you are looking for is "Design patterns".

Basically any code that you can compile and run is "OK" as far as the system is concerned.

You have to define your problem, define the restrictions, find all the tool you have at your hand and then decide what is the best design for you.

For a usual system I think what you are looking for is the composite design pattern.

In the composite pattern you provide a general enough interface to present the operations that are the same for all the components, further more each composite object may have children that are also composite. This you could think of as breaking down the structure. In your example,

```
                 computer
                /   |   \
              HDD  RAM  GPU
```

Each of these sub-parts may have their own sub parts as well.

This pattern is very well described in various places so I will not go any deeper into it.

[Here](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/composite) is one link to a description (the first one I found)

Also the book [Design patterns: elements of reusable object-oriented software](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612) is a must read in my mind.